# Как правильно переименовать проект asp.net core приложения

Tags: asp.net-core

Подскажите, есть ли верный способ переименовать проект asp.net core приложения, что бы обновились все ссылки и зависимости?

Answer (score 1):

Правой кнопкой на проект rename -> называем как надо.
Правой кнопкой на проект - > propirties -> application -> Assembly name и Default namespace называем как новое название проекта, сохраняем (Ctrl+s). Перезапустить проект.